# How to resize a real time flot chart?

Tags: javascript, browser, resize, flot

Is there a js library or a way to resize my real time flot chart when I resize the browser? My chart is like [this example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html). The difference between the example and my chart is that it is  put in a table.

**EDIT:**
I have found that `jquery.flot.resize.js` exists and does what I want. But does influence the library functionality the position of the flot in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative units to resize element relative to window size one of them is %. Set width and height of element in % it will resize this element according to %age size of parent. Example

```
Resize window to see results!
<div style="
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;">
      Resizeable DIV
</div>
```

Demonstration given here https://jsfiddle.net/7rtguhuv/

Comment: Sorry, but it is not I'm looking  for. See edited question.

Comment: No problem, It's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

I post the solution to my problem here. Maybe someone will need it.
I used `jquery.flot.resize.js` and the next code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="floatedTable">
            <tr>

                <td class="auto-style15">
                    <div id="content">
                    <div class="demo-container" style="position:absolute; width:75%; height:80%; top: 57px; left: 64px;">

            <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder" style="position:absolute; width:95%; height:95%; top: 17px; left: 24px;"></div>

            </div>
                        </div>
                </td>

            </tr>
            </table>
```

where `class="floatedTable"` is:

```
.floatedTable {
             width: 100%;
             height:100%;
           }
```